# how to reset class added by jquery when going back page in browser

Tags: jquery

I want to remove class added by jquery when going to previous page by clicking back page button on browser. Is there any simple solution? Please help and thanks!

Comment: You can try this https://codepen.io/balatd/pen/RwwQjRL